# Can the sentence "My shoelaces are so long that when I walk, they come under my shoes." be rephrased to a shorter, routine language sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

The *routine language* part in question is subjective, of course.

Comment: How about "my shoelaces are too long" ?  :-)

Comment: @Hellion I want to specifically mention shoes :) This sentence could also mean - 'My shoelaces are too long. They can be wrapped around earth.' :p

Comment: The default reason for *why* your shoelaces are too long is that you step on them occasionally (or frequently, or even constantly), either untying them or tripping yourself; if you don't explicitly state something else, or if some alternate use is not immediately evident from the situation, that's what will be assumed.

Comment: I don't think this is a proofreading question. OP is asking for commonly used phrases to describe a certain situation.

Comment: @user3169 Trolls don't need reason to be trolls. Well, that's what makes them trolls.

Comment: Suggested way to bring this question back on topic: "'come under' is awkward — is there a more appropriate phrase to use?"

Answer (score 3):

I guess the most common expression would be **I'm tripping on my shoelaces**. It isn't the same meaning sentence but occurs in pretty much the same situation, and will be much more "routine".

Comment: Sounds good buddy!

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

> I keep stepping on my shoelaces.

Answer (score -1):

"My shoelace come under the shoes when I walk. "

Implied in speech because the only way your shoe lace would come under the shoes is because they are too long.

Comment: "My _shoelaces_ come under _my_ shoes" is the correct way to write your sentence. A native speaker wouldn't use "come under" though.